# Hilt with Jetpack Compose Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation

I checked this info https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation how to inject `ViewModel` to a compose screen.

For now I implemeted like this for my test app:

```
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = startDestination,
    modifier = modifier
) {
    composable(Screen.Topics.name) {
        val parentEntry = remember { navController.getBackStackEntry(Screen.Topics.name) }
        val topicsViewModel = hiltViewModel<TopicsViewModel>(parentEntry)
        TopicsScreen(
            topicsViewModel = topicsViewModel,
            openDrawer = openDrawer,
            navigateToTopicDetails = { topic -> actions.navigateToTopicsDetails(topic) }
        )
    }
    ...
```

Is there will be any difference if I use

```
val parentEntry = remember { navController.getBackStackEntry(Screen.Topics.name) }
val topicsViewModel = hiltViewModel<TopicsViewModel>(parentEntry)
```

or just

```
val topicsViewModel = hiltViewModel<TopicsViewModel>()
```

I guess first one is needed only if we use nested graphs and we want to get ViewModel for specific graph scope https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav

So in my case the scope is the same for both methods if I don't use nested graphs?

So can I just use `hiltViewModel<TopicsViewModel>()` in my case?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already provided a clear explanation for your question, but to sum it up,
`hiltViewModel<TopicsViewModel>(parentEntry)` is used when you have nested navigation graphs. When you use hiltViewModel with parentEntry, you are telling Compose to create a ViewModel instance that is scoped to the nested graph.

Since you are not using nested graphs in your code, you can use the simpler version of `hiltViewModel` without parentEntry. This will create a ViewModel instance that is scoped to the current screen's navigation graph, which is what you want.